# Escape instagram in app browser to safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, instagram

I have a link in my website that redirects to instagram login to fetch some photos, but that page doesn't work on the in app browser from instagram, on an ios device.
My idea is to put a link so the user can click it and be redirected to a page in safari or the default browser, is that possible?

`<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: you can put link in App, when user will click, that will redirects to instagram .

Comment: Instagram login page doesn't work on In app instagram browser, on ios.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @kizoso no, sorry.

Comment: There's no way to do this AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but could be a clue.
Just put some blocking js code in the beginning of a html body.

```
<script>
    var str = navigator.userAgent;
    var i = str.indexOf("Instagram");
    if (i != -1) {
      document.write("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://instagram.com/?nibrowser=no\">Proceed to Sfari</a>");
      window.stop();
    }
</script>
```

Some info about Instagram user agent: https://mpulp.mobi/2016/07/12/instagram-user-agent/

On forcing in app browsers to open Safari: https://support.interact.technology/support/solutions/articles/17000003729-how-to-force-a-link-to-open-in-safari-ios-only-

And window.stop() just prevents page load almost in all browsers.
Hope it'll help.

Comment: That "nibrowser=no" part made no difference at all for me.

Comment: the detection worked (the in-app browser does have "Instagram" in its user agent), but neither the `_blank` target nor `nibrowser` helped to break out of the in-app browser. what's the way to do this in 2018? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the closest solution I could suggest is to use SfariView: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safari-view